# Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710 Not Working with Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-10, logitech-gamepad

I purchased a [Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-gamepad-f710) that is supposed to work with Windows 10, and so far it does not.

Windows 10 detects it when I plug in its wireless receiver and turn it on; but in Windows Device Manager, the gamepad shows with a yellow caution icon and is said to not be working properly.

I have tried the gamepad's XInput and DirectInput modes and installed Logitech Gaming Software for it.  In Device Manager, I have also tried:

- Automatically updating the gamepad's driver: Device Manager indicates that it cannot find an appropriate driver for it.
- Browsing to the folder under `C:\Users\Joe\appdata\Local\Temp` extracted by Logitech Gaming Software's InstallShield installer to update the gamepad's driver, indicating that Device Manager should check subfolders for an appropriate driver too: Device Manager again indicates that it cannot find an appropriate driver.

From the research I did online, I was unable to find a solution either.  Has someone on SU had this problem and found a way to resolve it?

Comment: Sounds like you should running the `Wireless Gamepad F710 Connect Utility` just to make sure it can't correct the problem.  So does Windows detect the device or not, based on what you wrote, I can't tell.

Comment: It detects it to the extent that it *shows* in Device Manager; but it has a yellow caution icon over it and is said to not be working properly (which is what I find when I try to use it).

Comment: You have manually pointed device manager to the correct .inf file?

Comment: I tried browsing to the folder under `C:\Users\Joe\appdata\Local\Temp` extracted by Logitech Gaming Software's InstallShield installer to update the gamepad's driver through Device Manager, indicating that Device Manager should check subfolders for an appropriate driver too: there are `.ini` and `.sys` files aplenty in and beneath that folder; but Device Manager reports that it cannot find an appropriate driver for the gamepad in any of those folders.

Comment: i suggest you open a support ticket with Logitech in that case.

Comment: Correction: *there are `.ini`, `.sys`, and `.inf` files aplenty....*

Comment: @Ramhound: I updated my question to make it clearer based on your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more digging, I learned in Logitech's support forums that [others have this issue too](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Logitech-G-Controllers/Logitech-F710-not-working-on-Windows-10/m-p/1440215#M24059), also that no one has a solution there either.

After *even more* digging, I found a fix, which I detailed there and below for completeness.

## Microsoft Community Solution

TheTexanGamer's Microsoft Community solution to a similar issue with an Xbox 360 wireless controller and Windows 10 seems to have resolved the problem for me: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/games_windows_10/xbox-360-wireless-controller-not-workingconnecting/b65687c2-f879-4a59-b074-248828e5d774?auth=1

I had to follow the steps outlined in TheTexanGamer's answer with the F710 in XInput mode:

> Make sure your controller is turned off and the wireless receiver is
>   plugged in to your PC before proceeding with the steps below:
>
> 1. Press Windows key+X.
> 2. Click "Device Manager".
> 3. Find any listings of "Unknown Device" in the list of devices, likely under Human Interface Devices or Other Devices. Make sure you
>      right click it and select the "Scan for hardware changes" and "Update
>      Driver Software" > "Search Automatically for Updated Driver" options
>      before the next steps, especially if you have more than one "Unknown
>      Device" listed.
> 4. Right-click on "Unknown Device" and click "Update Driver Software".
> 5. Click the option "Browse my computer for driver software".
> 6. Click the option "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
> 7. Near the bottom of the list, select the option that looks something like "Xbox 360 Peripherals" and click "Next".
> 8. From the list, select the driver option "Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows [2/15/2007]" and click "Next".
> 9. A warning will appear about the possibility of the device or your computer not working properly and likelihood of system instability.
>      Disregard it and click "Yes" in the bottom right corner of the panel.
> 10. A message should appear within a few seconds saying that the device has been correctly installed. Click "Ok" and exit out of all
>       device manager windows.
>
> After performing these steps, do as I did and power on your controller....

## Results

Screenshots of the results I got follow.

**Figure 1: Windows Device Manager After Following TheTexanGamer's Steps**
[image: Figure 1: Windows Device Manager After Following TheTexanGamer's Steps]

The Game Controllers control panel tells the rest of the story afterward.

**Figure 2: *Game Controllers* Control Panel (`joy.cpl`)**
[image: Figure 2: Game Controllers Control Panel (joy.cpl)]

**Figure 3: *Game Controllers > Advanced***
[image: Figure 3: Game Controllers > Advanced]

**Figure 4: *Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties***
[image: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties]

**Figure 5: *Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties* – D-Pad Pressed Up-Left**
[image: Figure 5: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties – D-Pad Up-Left Pressed]

**Figure 6: *Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties* – X Button Pressed**
[image: Figure 6: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties – X Button Pressed]

**Figure 7: *Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties* – Left Thumbstick Held Up-Left**
[image: Figure 7: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties – Left Thumbstick Held Up-Left]

**Figure 8: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties – Right Thumbstick Held Down-Right**
[image: Figure 8: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties – Right Thumbstick Held Down-Right]

**Figure 9: *Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties* – LT Button Pressed**
[image: Figure 9: Game Controllers > Controller (Wireless Gamepad F710) > Properties – LT Button Pressed]

## Possible Lingering Issues

- The LT and RT buttons affecting Z Axis in the Game Controllers control panel?  That does not seem right to me, but maybe I am mistaken.
- DirectInput?  The above solution did not work for me until I switched the gamepad to XInput mode.

Answer (score 1):

> **Following the release of Windows 10 May 2020 Update (2004), the currently accepted solution no longer works.**

Although the driver can be installed, it does not survive a reboot and generates a "device not migrated" error message. There is a workaround documented on Reddit and the official Microsoft forums but it involves installing a modified (and unsigned) XBox 360 driver from a Google Drive URL.

https://github.com/mrsilver76/Logitech-F710-Windows-driver consolidates that information (and driver) into a single location and download with clear steps on how to install.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the latest.  The following from the GitHub page you referenced is particularly noteworthy to evolve the accepted answer with the issue, however: "As soon as Logitech provide an official working and signed alternative driver then this content will be removed."

Comment: @J0e3gan I found a YouTube video which suggests that Logitech have known about the issue for about six months. I’d prefer an official signed driver (and will replace the workaround with it) but it looks like Logitech aren’t in much of a hurry :(